# How do custom projections work in d3 3.0?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet

I tried porting Mike Bostock's [Leaflet + d3 mashup](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/leaflet/) to the most recent release of d3 3.0, but I'm having some issues with the "projection" line:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (x){
    var point = self.map.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(x[1], x[0]));
    return [point.x, point.y];
} has no method 'point'
```

The way custom projects work seems to have changed significantly, but I'm not quite sure how.

Could anyone shed some light on how the Leaflet + d3 example might look in d3 3.0?

Comment: It has changed a lot in v3, but it is not officially released yet. Once v3 is out and there is some documentation this will hopefully be cleared up a little. I do believe there are plans to update many of the examples, including, hopefully, the d3 + Leaflet example.

Comment: so, d3.v3 was released more than 2 months ago. I'm wondering whether there is a solution available now?